# How would you structure a forum thread with reports in firebase firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am developing a forum feature of an app, and already made a working structure and it looks like this:

[image]

So basically I have a `threads` collection, and inside each thread there is a `comments` collection.

Now I want users to be able to report a `thread` or a `comment`. I'm thinking of two ways to do this:

1. Create a new collection for `reports`, and each `report` will contain a `threadId`, `userId`, `text`, and `commentId` (if the reported item is a `comment`).
2. Each thread will have a `reports` collection, and each `comment` will have a `reports` collection (which I think is too nested).

Is there any other way to do this? How would you go over this scenario?

Comment: I would focus on first defining the queries that need to be performed, then structuring the data around those requirements.  Give that nosql databases can't effectively "join" data between collections, you could easily design something that needs to be changed later.

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson. I'll take that advice.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the comments, the best approach would be to first, focus in the defining the queries and how the data needs to be retrieved. Due to th fact NoSQL databases don't use the same way of queries that normal SQL do, in case you design your scheme without focusing on your way of returning first, it could cause rework after.

To summarize, focusing first in the queries and then in designing, it's probably the best idea. Thanks @DougStevenson for the help in the comments.